# How do I reduce memory required to view .usdz objects in AR?

Tags: ios, arkit

Im playing with ARKit in a `Messages extension` and I'm able to load and show the sample tv and wheelbarrow files, but I'm getting memory warnings for the tv and it's not that big really.

Are there any techniques I can use to reduce the memory requirements for using this object file? This is from a subclass of SCNNode.

```
func loadModel() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: VirtualObject.self)
    guard let fileURL = bundle.url(forResource: "retrotv", withExtension: "usdz")
        , let modelNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: fileURL)
        else { return }

    modelNode.load()
    modelNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.005, 0.005, 0.005)

    self.addChildNode(modelNode)
    modelLoaded = true
}
```

The rest of the code is from using Apple's UIKit example.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but crucial are texture resolutions (not file size). When you rename .USDZ file to .ZIP you can actually unzip it and see what is inside. There are textures + .USDC file. Textures here are either RGB (3B/px) or Greyscale (2B/px) and all of them are 2k (2048px x 2048px).

So, for example if you have iPhone X which have retina display that scales each side of image 3 times it means, that device needs (2048 * 3) * (2048 * 3) * 3 = 113MB of RAM memory to display 2k RGB rexture.

This retro TV has four 2k RGB textures and four 2k Greyscale texture, we could calculate that textures alone are aprox. (4 * 113MB) + (4 * 75MB) = 752MB of RAM.

For more info I highly recommend this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416).